# Sorting Logs (Serilog) output in ascending order?

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

How to make`"$type": "IqhApplicationEndEvent"` to come first in the list under "diagnostic" ?

```
  {
     "@t": "2018-12-03",
     "@mt": "{@Diagnostic}",
     "Diagnostic": {
            "ShutdownReason": "HostingEnvironment",
            "Timestamp": "2018-12-03",
            "MachineName": "local",
            "AdditionalInfo": {},
            "$type": "IqhApplicationEndEvent"
        }
   }
```

Method :

```
 public void WriteAudit(DiagnosticTest diagnostic)
    {
        _Logger?.Write(LogEventLevel.Information, "{@Diagnostic}", diagnostic);
    }
```

Expected output:

```
{
     "@t": "2018-12-03",
     "@mt": "{@Diagnostic}",
     "Diagnostic": {
            "$type": "IqhApplicationEndEvent" ---------Sorted to the top
            "ShutdownReason": "HostingEnvironment",
            "Timestamp": "2018-12-03",
            "MachineName": "local",
            "AdditionalInfo": {},

        }
   }
```

Comment: What's your problem again?

Comment: $type property is logged by default when using serilogs, since I cannot remove it, I'd like it to be displayed as the first property in the logs. Example added.